# trace() not working. Flash

Tags: flash

I chose new actionscript file(3.0) and wrote as simple as `trace("Hello World");`, but it is not working. I have flash player 10 and i also made sure i have not checked omit trace statements in publish settings. Where am i going wrong? Please help.

Comment: Are you using the Flash IDE? Which version? Where did you place the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the answer to my own question. On upper right of output panel, there is some silly icon, i clicked it and changed from none to "verbose". Works smooth and fine now :)